# Problem while using sprintf in C and getting warning

Tags: c, printf

Whenever I am trying to use sprintf() while coding in C, I am getting a warning saying :

> "warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 49 bytes into a region of size
> 39 [-Wformat-overflow=]"

It is also producing a note saying :

> "note: ‘sprintf’ output between 13 and 62 bytes into a destination of
> size 50    62 |   sprintf(msg,"fopen-ing "%s"",data_file);"

Below I am giving some part of my code, mainly where I am getting this warning.

```
char data_file[50]; // Global

void initialize_from_data_file()
{
    FILE *fpS;
    if((fpS = fopen(data_file,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        char msg[50];
        sprintf(msg,"fopen-ing \"%s\"",data_file);
        perror(msg);
        exit(1);
    }
    ...
}
```

As I am newly using this language so unable to understand how to remove this warning.

Comment: `msg` is too small to accommodate the result of `sprintf`.

Comment: msg is a buffer cointaing space for 50 characters and you're sending (potentially) 50 characters (from data_file) + 12 extra chars in the format string. The compiler is warning you that this could overflow. You should alloc more space in the msg buffer.

Comment: Do you understand what `sprintf` does? Can you estimate how many characters it's going to produce? Can you verify if that output fits the destination array?

Comment: The messages are pretty clear. You want to produce a string and store it in a space that is not large enough for it.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's warning you that the destination buffer for `sprintf` might not be big enough to hold the string you want to put in it.  If `data_file` is more than around 40 characters long, `sprintf` will write past the end of the array `msg`.

Make `msg` big enough to hold the string that would go in it:

```
char msg[70];
```

There's another problem however.  Since you call `sprintf` right before calling `perror`, the latter will reporting the error status of the `sprintf` call, not the `fopen` call.

So don't use `sprintf` at all in this case and use `strerror` to get the error string:

```
fprintf(stderr,"fopen-ing \"%s\": %s",data_file,strerror(errno));
```